# NULL as a parameter

Tags: c++

I am a bit confused when you pass NULL as a parameter

for example

```
  int*  array_create( int* array,size)
  {
    array = new int[size];
    return array;
  }     

  int main()
  {
    int* array = array_create(NULL,10);//can we pass NULL in this case?
    delete[] array;
    return 0;
  }
```

I know the example is kinda stupid, but I am wondering if we can pass NULL as the parameter when the function assigns some heap memory to a pointer and returns it?

Comment: Yes you can. Although with c++11 we use nullptr instead. It is however kind of pointless to have array as a parameter in this case.

Comment: @drescherjm couldn't think of a better example. What I wanted to know was that when you pass NULL, you dont have the variable like how `array = new int[size]`, I wasnt sure if NULL would work

Comment: `array` is still a variable, it's just that its initial value is NULL (or `nullptr`).

Comment: @Lzy If you´re using the passed pointer to access an value (including arrays), then NULL is a problem. But you´re not using the passed address at all, you´re just assigning a new valid address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your function like this...

```
int* array = array_create(NULL,10);//can we pass NULL in this case?
```

...you are getting behaviour like:

```
int* array_create(...)
{
    int* array = NULL;
    size_t size = 10;   // using size_t as you'd missed any type
    array = new int[size];
    return array;
}
```

Ultimately, `array` is initialised to `NULL` then shortly afterwards overwritten with the value returned by `new`, so the initialisation serves no purpose.

For this code, there was simply no point passing an `array` argument... you could have created a local variable directly:

```
int* array_create(size_t n)
{
    int* array = new int[size];
    return array;
}
```

...or even...

```
int* array_create(size_t n)
{
    return new int[size];
}
```

---

> I am wondering if we can pass NULL as the parameter when the function assigns some heap memory to a pointer and returns it?

This requirement doesn't make much sense, as the two things are unrelated.  You can pass whatever you like, and return whatever you like.

---

More commonly, a function might do something like:

```
void dump_bytes(std::ostream& os, unsigned char* p, size_t n)
{
    if (p)
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            os << static_cast<int>(p[i]) << ' ';
}
```

In `dump_bytes`, specifying a `p` value of `NULL` would fail the `if (p)` condition, ensuring the function didn't invoke undefined behaviour by dereferencing via a NULL pointer, even if `n` was not `0`.

Comment: I thought in the original one inside the function, it uses the variable array and I was confused what would be created if I pass a nullptr

Comment: @Lzy: so is it clear to you now, or still not sure?  If not, please ask some questions or explain your understanding so we can try to help further....

Answer (score 1):

Just summarizing from the comments:

Yes, it is completely valid, but in Your example it is completely useless (you know that)

Some examples of this in real code:

In OpenGL you can tell the API if the data you want is coming from is from a buffer:

```
  glBufferData(..., nullptr);
```

But wait! That's not null, that's nullptr?

Well in a c++11 compiler nullptr is a better option. Because NULL often usually resolves to 0, a version of the method that takes an int instead of a pointer the compiler will choose the int.

Here's some more data on that:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr

Also, if you want to edit an array, you should pass a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: also I forgot to ask, when we pass NULL, what type is it? cuz in the function, the parameter is supposed to be a `int*` ,and inside the function, it uses `array`(in the example).When NULL is passed, would it be `NULL = new int[size]`?

Comment: No. You are assigning the int* array to the value returned by new int[size]. The old value will be discarded. That's why it's useless how you are using that argument in that function.

Comment: but when Ithe nullptr is passed, where is the`new int[size]` passed to?

Comment: @Lzy `new int[size]` isn't passed anywhere. The nullptr pointed to by `int* array` is replaced with the `new int[size]` which is then returned to the caller. A good example of using  NULL as a parameter is in [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) (a function I don't recomend using without really good reason, but a good example regardless) The first time you call it, you set the string you want tokenized. Subsequent strtok calls to parse the same string are passed NULL.